# React JS: Private Route preserve uri on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Say a user directly loads a page: `http://localhost:3000/home/view` which is a protected page.

Since I am using [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) with it's `isSignedIn` as true, it uses a `useEffect` type of mechanism to check if a user is already logged in or not.

Now my issue is that since initially user is not logged in, it redirects the users to login page: `http://localhost:3000/` where useEffect takes place and verifies the `isLoggedIn` property.

Now once the verification is done, I want user to get redirected to the page he was browsing on which was `http://localhost:3000/home/view` but in this case he remains on the `http://localhost:3000/` even after verification. I want to add a callback in `onSuccess` which redirects user back to the page where he came from.

Here is my LoginPage (`http://localhost:3000/`):

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Login.module.scss';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
import { processUserLogin, userData } from './slices/userSlice';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Spinner from '../shared/ui-components/spinner/spinner';

export default function Login(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector(userData);
  const isPending = user.status === 'loading';
  const responseGoogleSuccess = (response) => {
    const payload = {
      operationType: 'configureUserAndGetDetails',
      payLoad: {
        email: response.profileObj.email,
        google_payload: response,
      },
    };
    dispatch(processUserLogin(payload));
  };
  const responseGoogleFailed = (response) => {
    console.log('User Login Failed = ', response);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.LoginPage}>
      {isPending && <Spinner />}
      {user.userSignedIn ? (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/view', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      ) : (
        <GoogleLogin
          clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
          buttonText='Login'
          onSuccess={responseGoogleSuccess}
          onFailure={responseGoogleFailed}
          cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
          isSignedIn={true}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's my `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './features/shared/hoc/Layout/Layout';
import LoginPage from './features/login-page/login';
import { FRONTEND_ROUTES } from './features/shared/backend/frontendRoutes';
import { ComponentRoutes } from './AppRoutes';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userData } from './features/login-page/slices/userSlice';
// import PrivateRoute from './features/shared/hoc/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';

function App(props) {
  const user = useSelector(userData);
  const isUserSignedIn = user.userSignedIn;
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/view' component={ComponentRoutes.asyncView} />
      <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />
      <Redirect to='/' />
    </Switch>
  );

  if (isUserSignedIn || false) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={FRONTEND_ROUTES.CONFIG_PAGE}
          component={ComponentRoutes.asyncConfig}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={FRONTEND_ROUTES.CONFIG_PAGE_REST}
          component={ComponentRoutes.asyncConfig}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={FRONTEND_ROUTES.ADVERTISERS_PAGE}
          component={ComponentRoutes.asyncView}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={FRONTEND_ROUTES.VIEWS_PAGE}
          component={ComponentRoutes.asyncAdvertiserPage}
        />

        <Route
          exact
          path='/schedule'
          component={ComponentRoutes.asyncConstruction}
        />
        <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path='/' component={ComponentRoutes.asyncNotFound} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>{routes}</Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

How do I solve this issue

Comment: your `GoogleLogin` needs to know `props.location` as well, so you need to pass that in case you are redirecting to the login. And then after the login, you then redirect to this.

Comment: props.location gives me `/` but I want to have previous route

Comment: Use `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom` to redirect user to http://localhost:3000/home/view with `history.push("/home/view");`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this issue by passing props through Redirect as shown below:

`<Redirect to={{ to: '/', prevPath: location.pathname }} />`

And then using the same path in my Login as shown below:-

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Login.module.scss';
import { userData } from './slices/userSlice';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Spinner from '../shared/ui-components/spinner/spinner';
import GoogleLoginPage from './GoogleLoginPage';

export default function Login(props) {
  const user = useSelector(userData);
  const isPending = user.status === 'loading';
  return (
    <div className={classes.LoginPage}>
      {isPending && <Spinner />}
      {user.userSignedIn ? (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: props.location.prevPath,
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <GoogleLoginPage previousLocation={props.location} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```